# I want to transfer data from one sheet to another based on the count of rows present in a particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets. I want to count the number of rows present in column "A" of "instru" sheet and drag the formula present in (A1:D1) of sheet "data" based on the count of rows present in sheet "instru".
I've tried this but it doesn't work. I am new to VBA and I really don't know where I've gone wrong.

```
Sub lastRow()

    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
    Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
    Dim lastR As Long

    Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru")
    Set wsS2 = Sheets("data")

    With wsS1
        lastR = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        With wsS2
            Row.range("A5:KU5" & lastR).Copy wsS2.range("A1")
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I am counting this column present in Sheet "instru"
[image: IMG1]

[this is the formula (orange coloured row) sheet which i want drag based on the number of rows present in the sheet instru](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIxI6.png)

Comment: can you post an example your sheet and what do you want obtain? So we can help...
in your code there isn't .Row and you there have an error...
 lastR = .range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row...And you never use sheet "data"

Comment: please check the two images added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. I didnt include the headers in "Instru". As in `Range("A1:B4")`

This procedure is based on Column Count in Row 1

```
Sub lastRow()

Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long

Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("data")

With wsS1
    lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
End With

With wsS2
    lastC = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address, .Cells(1, lastC).Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)

End With
End Sub
```

**-- EDIT --**

This procedure is based on Column Count in Row 3

```
Sub lastRow2()

Dim wsS1 As Worksheet 'Sheet1
Dim wsS2 As Worksheet 'sheet2
Dim lastR As Long, lastC As Long

Set wsS1 = Sheets("Instru")
Set wsS2 = Sheets("data")

With wsS1
    lastR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 4
End With

With wsS2
    lastC = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(3, lastC).Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range(.Cells(3, 1).Address, .Cells(lastR, lastC).Address)

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this is giving me the expected output but it only drags Column "A and B" what about the other columns?

Comment: in "data" sheet Row A3:KU3 will have formulas.... and yes the number or rows and columns are referenced to sheet "instru"

Comment: didnt work! i just want to count the number of rows present in "instru" sheet Column "A" and then drag the formula already present in A3:KU3 on the basis of the count of rows... so if the count of row is = 1440 then it will drag all the formulas present upto 1440 rows

Comment: the first one was working fine ...it just didnt drag all the columns with formula present in the sheet "data"

Comment: _Happy to help, and again, welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted._

Comment: try the **second** procedure I updated _This procedure is based on Column Count in Row 3_

Comment: much welcome. I was a VBA newbie once myself and I found that stepping through the code (pressing F8) helped me understand how the codes work and allowed me to play with it and eventually figure out what to change / what's wrong :)